# Issue with firewalld

Tags: firewalld, firewall-cmd, firewalld-zone

I just came across this issue and it's late here so I can't really think straight anymore right now. Still this is something pretty simple so I'm not really seeing what I'm missing and just going nuts here:

I was setting up a server I use solely for running docker containers.
I started with a MariaDB container all ok here and I decided to connect to it just to make sure all is working.

So now I want to connect to server running MariaDB, and since I'm behind firewalld, I started by configuring it by adding a new zone to firewall-cmd, add service and source:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone=test-from-home
firewall-cmd --reload
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=test-from-home --add-service=mysql
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=test-from-home --add-source=XX.XX.XX.XX/32
firewall-cmd --reload
```

And I connected perfectly using `mysql -u root -p -h host`
All great!

Running `firewall-cmd --get-active-zones` returns:

```
[root@nd01 latest]# firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
test-from-home
  sources: XX.XX.XX.XX/32
public
  interfaces: eth0
```

So just because sometimes I remember making these tests to make sure everything is working, I connected to another machine and I connected successfully from this other IP.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=test-from-home --list-all
test-from-home (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: XX.XX.XX.XX/32
  services: mysql
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources: 
  services: ssh dhcpv6-client
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Why am I being able to connect from a random machine?
What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: What did you try to connect to?

Comment: Sorry mate I didn’t fully understand your question. I connected using mysql command on my machine,  and also connected using app navicat. From the remote I used mysql cmd. And I also asked a friend to netcat to host port 3306. All successful when I was expecting only my connections (originated in my IP/32) would go through. Sorry multi edits i’m on the phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so today I found the answer,

### FirewallD doesn't play nice with Docker (or vice-versa)

Meanwhile I came across the fact that FirewallD and Docker do not play along.
According to the Docker documentation, the way to circumvent this is by disabling IPTables:
- [Docker and iptables](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/)

As it says from the very first stance:

> On Linux, Docker manipulates `iptables` rules to provide network isolation. This is an implementation detail, and you should not modify the rules Docker inserts into your `iptables` policies.

Which wouldn't be my first resort as adviced against.

So I did a little more digging and I found a page that gave me the answer and  anyone with this issue can take a couple of ideas from it, it's a nice approach to it, by adding configuration to the DOCKER-USER chain.

> [Docker meets firewall - finally an answer](https://unrouted.io/2017/08/15/docker-firewall/)